# How can I open a PDF file with FileReader and get the path?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I want to display a PDF file with the following code. So far everything works fine, the file 'Test.pdf' opens. Now I want to be able to select a file via an "File-Open" dialog.

I tried different approaches and was able to get a "file-open"-dialog to select a file. But I don't know how to open the file in the viewer.
Can anyone help me with this?

How do I create the dialog and pass the file to the viewer?

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

    <iframe id="viewer"></iframe>

    <script>

    page = 1;
    let reader = new FileReader();

    function updateViewerURL() {
      let viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
      viewer.src = reader.result;
    }

    reader.addEventListener('load', updateViewerURL);
  
    fetch('Test.pdf')
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob.slice(0, blob.size, 'application/pdf'));
    });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A file-open dialog selects files on the client. The code you posted gets the file from the server. Do you want the user to be able to use a file-open dialog to select server files? I don't think that's possible. You could use an API to return a list of filenames, and display that as an ordinary dropdown menu.

Comment: You also can't get the path of a file from a file-open dialog selecting a client file. There are many security issues with allowing that.

Comment: you don't need to get the pathname. You can pass the File object in `inputElement.files[0]` to `FileReader`.

Comment: @Barmar: The server runs on a local machine and can be reached via <local-ip:port>. The user should be able to select a local file (not on the server) to be displayed, not a file from the server.

Comment: Then you don't need to use `fetch()`. Just read the file that they select in the dialog.

Comment: Ah, I see... I will give it a try, see if I get it working and come back. Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: @Barmar: I removed the `fetch()` part and started with `input type="file" id="openPDF" accept=".pdf,application/pdf" />` to access the file.
I can select a file ,but I don't know how to pass the file to the reader and get it displayed in the browser. Can you help me with some more detailed code? 
Sorry for this basic questions...

Comment: Isn't the code in the linked question helpful?